# I want to reconstruct django view

Tags: python, django

view.py

```
class ListDoctor(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = DoctorList.objects.filter(h_code="h_0001")
    serializer_class = DoctorListSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        doctor = DoctorList.objects.values()
        return Response(
            {
                "doctor": doctor
            }
        )
```

data:

```
"doctor": [
    {
        "doctorname": "testname1",
        "position": "ST",
        "h_code_id": "h_0000",
        "d_code": "d_0000"
    },
    {
        "doctorname": "testname2",
        "position": "CB",
        "h_code_id": "h_0000",
        "d_code": "d_0001"
    },
    {
        "doctorname": "testname3",
        "position": "CM",
        "h_code_id": "h_0001",
        "d_code": "d_0002"
    },
    {
        "doctorname": "testname4",
        "position": "GK",
        "h_code_id": "h_0001",
        "d_code": "d_0003"
     }
]
```

I would like to change the above code like below.

```
"h_0000" [
    {
        "doctorname" : "testname1",
        "position" : "ST",
        "h_code_id: "h_0000",
        "d_code" : "d_0000"
    },
    {
        "doctorname" : "testname2"
        "position" : "CB"
        "h_code_id: "h_0000",
        "d_code" : "d_0001"
    }
"h_0001" [
    {
        "doctorname" : "testname3",
        "position" : "CM",
        "h_code_id: "h_0001",
        "d_code" : "d_0002"
    },
    {
        "doctorname" : "testname4"
        "position" : "GK",
        "h_code_id: "h_0001",
        "d_code" : "d_0003"
    }
```

How can I change the data above to look like below?

We sincerely appreciate those who respond.

h_code_id(h_0001, h_0002, h_0003...) will increase gradually. Therefore, it cannot be manually created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to transform the data in different format.

```
def list(self, request):
    data = {}
    doctors = DoctorList.objects.values()
    for doctor in doctors:
        try:
           data[doctor["h_code_id"]].append(doctor)
        except KeyError:
           data[doctor["h_code_id"]] = [doctor]

    return Response(data)
```

Comment: you can use `defaultdict` so try except is unnessesary. `from collections import defaultdict    data=defaultdict(list)  data[doctor["h_code_id"]].append(doctor)`